# 2 date conditions followed by counting a different column formula not working on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B261,and(AT:AT<=DATE(2021,12,31),AU:AU>=DATE(2022,2,1)))
```

The formula looks simple but is just not working on Excel for some reason.

The formula I need in words are as follows: Filter on column AT with dates that are on or before 31/12/2021 and filter on column AU with dates that are on or after 01/02/2022.

Then count the number of filtered rows on column B.

I just can't seem to figure out why it's not working when it makes perfect sense logically and in a formula sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Subtotal does not "filter" it Ignores data that has been filtered out using the data filter.

Comment: You want to filter 3 columns? SUBTOTAL,3 is CONTA. and the and(AT:AT<=DATE(2021,12,31),AU:AU>=DATE(2022,2,1)) is not wrong.